# I want to learn transcribing music, where should I start?

Tags: sheet-music, composition, musescore, composers

I found a music notation app called Musescore, I fell in love with exploring it and started recreating music scores from another user's score for my practice, and also I started to learn video tutorials and courses about composing music.

I want to know what should I do first if I want to transcribe music into a score/music sheet.

As a newbie, I really appreciate any tips from you.

I am really happy to see all of your perspectives in the comment section guys... yes my question is too general because I'm not asking for advanced advice but just want to know the basic stuff like the learning path or how the writing score for any instruments (composing a piece) is work. make own music is every musician's dream but for now I really happy if I can understand the basics of writing notation just from hearing it.

Comment: *Transcription* means typically to rewrite for  different instruments, which might have other restrictions (so you have to modify the notes) or be transposing instruments. The first topic is quite advanced and can't be recommended to newbies.

Comment: @guidot No, it doesn't. To transcribe something is simply to create a written score for music that you only know as a recorded performance.

Comment: This question is very broad.  Are you looking for help getting started composing your own music?

Comment: @guidot What you are talking about is *arrangement*, transcription is the process of taking something in some written form and putting it into a different written form. This is sometimes used for a change in Alphabet. The term is also used for phonetic translation of spoken language into text, or more broadly also a translation of spoken language into written form. In music the term is used in a similar way for translation of played music into notated music.

Comment: @KilianFoth - For multi-instrument pieces, that's even harder than transcribing for a solo instrument. At least you can afford to be inaccurate (e.g. shift note octaves, add notes corresponding to drum beats) when transcribing those pieces for solo instruments. Transcribe all instruments instead and you need one heck of an ear for detail: you need to get *every instrument right*.

Comment: Welcome! This can't be answered right now because it's not quite clear what you want to do, and what your current comfort and abilities are. It sounds like you've been copying others' notated music (learning how Musescore operates). Are you also comfortable reading and writing in staff notation already? Are you asking for practical tips in writing your own music, or about how to write down music that you hear? Do you play an instrument? What level of music theory are you already comfortable with (notes? keys? diatonic harmonic functions? form?)?

Comment: I'm voting to close as "lacking details or clarity." Please use the "Edit" button below the question to add to it, and I'll gladly retract that vote.

Comment: There are numerous other relevant questions here that might address problems you will run into. Just type "transcribe" in the search box.

Comment: (Or, if the question is really about getting started composing, plenty of those too. General advice would be to get a bit of a crash course in the fundamentals of music theory; [musictheory.net](https://www.musictheory.net/lessons) is a decent place to start. And if you don't currently play an instrument, that can help; perhaps some beginning keyboard skills.)

Comment: I know this isn't usually done here, but you can DM me on Musescore.com at Rose Egbert and I'll give you as much ongoing help as you need.

Comment: This *is* kind of answerable, in very broad strokes & without getting too complex. You need to break down the disciplines, then send the OP off in the direction of the 'easiest' first, with a route map.